# Virtual attributes and mass-assignment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

developers! I can't understand next situation

For Example I have model

```
class Pg::City < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :country  
   #virtual accessors
   attr_accessor :population
   #attr_accessible :city, :isdisabled,  :country_id

end
```

I can use code like this:

```
c = Pg::City.new({:population=>1000})
puts c.population
1000
```

But if I uncomment attr_accessible code above throw warning

```
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: population
```

How can I use virtual attributes for mass-assigmnment together with model attributes?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried adding `:population` to the arguments you're passing to `attr_accessible`?

Comment: just tried  c = Pg::City.new({:population=>1000, :city=>"somename"}) .... warning

Comment: Did you try that with commented `attr_accessible` line?

Comment: without warning....so what should I do to except attributes from mass-assignment ? I think I must add them with attr_protected..

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Using `attr_accessor` to add a variable does not automatically add it to `attr_accessible`. If you are going to use `attr_accessible`, then you will need to add `:population` to the list:

```
attr_accessor :population
attr_accessible :city, :isdisabled, :country_id, :population
```