# rails - get other values from nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

I'm doing a sort of a book manager, so each user have their collection of books. What I've done is this

```
<%= simple_form_for @user_collection do |f|%>
  <%= f.input :user%>
  <%= f.input :collection_name%>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :collection_books do |builder|%>
    <%= builder.input :book_name%>
    <div class="author"><%= builder.input :author%></div>
    <div class="year"><%= builder.input :year%></div>
  <%end%>
<%end%>
```

I use that view in order to relate books to a user.

Here the book_name input is an autocomplete field[1] that searchs for book names, when a book is clicked, the author and year inputs fills with the information that I grabbed from the search.

Also I'm using links[2] in order to add more books.
The code that I show here doesn't show the other fields, 
As an example in my Collection model I have this validation line

```
validates_presence_of :collection_name
```

so If I try to save that collection with no collection_name it renders that view again as expected, but the problem comes because I'm just using the accessor attributes in order to show the book information, not because I want to save them.

Collection.rb

```
  attr_accessible :collection_books_attributes ... (and others)
  has_many :collection_books
  has_many :books, :through => :collection_books
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :collection_books
```

CollectionBook.rb

```
  attr_accessible :book_name
  attr_accessor :author, :year
```

Is there a way to store this values just in params without a mass assignment error?
Because every time I try to save, they are including those accessors I created in order to show the author and year of the book if there's an error (as I mentioned before).

Hope my problem is clear enough :)

Thanks in advance

Javier

[1] http://railscasts.com/episodes/102-auto-complete-association-revised
[2] http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised

Answer (score 0):

I tought that if I add an attr_accessor, there's no need to add that in the attr_accessible list. Now I'm retrieving the book information.

I found a hint here

[Virtual attributes and mass-assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005567/virtual-attributes-and-mass-assignment)